# How to bundle js library for use in browser with webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack, browser

I'm trying to create a minified version of a js library with webpack.

The library consists of one main function with prototypes that is exported and of several other functions it depends on that are imported in the file of the main function. This works without bundling and I assume that this file should the entry point for webpack.

I aim to bundle it into some mylib.min.js to be able access it in the browser like I would use jQuery or similar libraries. So I don't want to bundle the whole web app, just the JS library I wrote.

I'm not really getting along with it, since all tutorials show how to bundle the whole web app. My questions are:

- how do I have to export the main function of the library to be able to access it in the browser?
- how do I need to configure webpack?
- how should I include and access the bundle in the browser?

If you could recommend any example (like tutorial, gitub repository that does this, ...) I would be happy! Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Have you read the section on [authoring libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) in the Webpack docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you look at the documentation on the webpack website?

Here an example

For widespread use of the library, we would like it to be compatible in different environments, i.e. CommonJS, AMD, Node.js and as a global variable. To make your library available for consumption, add the library property inside output:

```
webpack.config.js

  var path = require('path');

  module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
-     filename: 'webpack-numbers.js'
+     filename: 'webpack-numbers.js',
+     library: 'webpackNumbers'
    },
    externals: {
      lodash: {
        commonjs: 'lodash',
        commonjs2: 'lodash',
        amd: 'lodash',
        root: '_'
      }
    }
  };
```

If you have any other question about that specific documentation just google webpack js authoring libraries. you'll be redirect to the good website. Website are subject to change pattern.

Comment: The "library" property is what I was missing. Now it's working :-) Thank you very much!